# According to my code , output results to . The expected output is 5. What is the mistake I am making?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, output

We have to enter a array size which is n = 5. Then we sort the arrays on basis of their index in lists such as Odd and Even index. Then I am adding the second last element, it should result in 7 but I am getting 5.
Inputs numbers are 3 4 1 7 9

I tried the code below and getting a result 5 instead of 7. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

```
n = []
odd = []
even = []
nsize = 5
for i in range(0, nsize):
    num = int(input("Enter number: "))
    n.append(num)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even.append(n[i])
    else:
        odd.append(n[i])

print("odd", sorted(odd))
print("even", sorted(even))
print(odd[-2] + even[-2])
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) does not modify the `odd` or `even` lists; instead it builds a new sorted list from the given list. To sort `odd` and `even` in-place, use [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort). Thus, change

```py
print("odd", sorted(odd))
print("even", sorted(even))
```

to

```py
odd.sort()
even.sort()
print("odd", odd)
print("even", even)
```

and it'll work as expected.

---

As far as naming conventions go, a function using the past participle of a verb (such as "sorted", "reversed", etc.) will typically not *modify* the input but rather return a *modified* copy of the input.
A function which uses the imperative (such as `sort`) *may* modify the input, though this is often not the case (e.g. `map` creates a new iterable). In languages which support it, such functions sometimes get an exclamation mark `!` appended to their names (as in `sort!`) to make their imperative nature (the possibly unexpected mutation of the input) clear.